# function to rebalance binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am working on implementing a binary search tree. One of the functions required to complete the implementation is a rebalance function.

According to the specifications the function works in the following way:

> The rebalance() method should create a balanced tree and thereby reduce skewness to zero. A
>   balanced tree is one in which the size of the left and right subtrees differ by no more than 1,
>   throughout the tree (i.e., every subtree is also balanced).
>
> To balance the tree, the rebalance() method should repeatedly move the root value to the smaller
>   subtree, and move the min/max value from the larger subtree to the root, until the tree is balanced.
>   It should then recursively balance both subtrees.

So far I have the following code:

```
    struct treeNode {
    Type value;
    int count;
    treeNode* left;
    treeNode* right;
    };
    treeNode* root;

template <class Type>
void bstree<Type>::rebalance(treeNode* sroot){

    if (root == NULL) {
        throw new underflow_error("tree is empty");
    }

    while (skewness(sroot) != 0)
    {
        if (size(sroot->left) < size(sroot->right))
        {
            sroot->left.insert(sroot->value);
            sroot->left.insert(max(sroot->right));
            sroot->left.insert(min(sroot->right));

        }
        else
        {
            sroot->right.insert(sroot->value);
            sroot->left.insert(max(sroot->left));
            sroot->left.insert(min(sroot->left));
        }
    }

    rebalance(sroot->left);
    rebalance(sroot->right);
}
```

I can't tell if I have followed the specifications correctly or not. Can I get some insight or pointers as where I may have done things wrong?

Comment: @phaazon: I suppose yours was worthy of framing, after you'd been coding for a couple of months.

Comment: @phaazon You could at least make a couple of suggestions to OP about his style

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29

Answer (score 4):

You have not followed the specifications correctly. For one thing, your `rebalance` operation increases the size of the tree. For another, the result is not always a binary search tree.

You must understand how these trees work before you attempt to implement them. There is just no way around that. I advise you to study your text (or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)) and try constructing and balancing some trees with pencil and paper.

Comment: i appreciate the advice